# Custom data annotation to hide property based on another's value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, angularjs-injector

Having a nightmare figuring this out and I am now flat against the brick wall

Using MVC framework I'm building essentially a simple form.
I'm keeping the view as simple as possible and using just editorForModel()

So within this forms model I'm using data annotations to add some more customisations to the properties.
I would like to create a custom data annotation, one that will hide the property it has been placed against based on the value of another property.

E.g

I have a drop down with yes or no.

And a field for name.
When the drop down is no it hides the name field in the form.

I can achieve this with JS but it would be nice going forward to have this as a simple data annotation for the model.

E.g [HideField("dropdown", "no")]

Thanks in advance

Comment: A data annotation will not solve this. Its server side code and cant 'react' to client side events. Javascript/jquery is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to handle this on the client side, not server side (using an Attribute).

If you're already using jQuery, something like this would do. Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y28q1or0/1/).

```
$(function () {
    var dropdown = $('#dropdown').change(function (event) {
        if ($(this).val() == "no") {
            $('#fieldToHide').hide();
        } else {
            $('#fieldToHide').show();
        }
    });
});
```

The reason you want to do it on the client side is pretty simple, any other method would require a post back with every change of the dropdown to check the value..

** **EDIT** **
From comment:

> Is it possible to inject this JavaScript into the page... ...Rather than having the essentially the same script duplicated on each page

This could be rewritten, a little more generic, so it could be reused on different pages. Add it to yoursite.js (which you should already have..) and then simply wire it up on each page as desired.  Updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y28q1or0/5/).

Site.JS

```
function hideIf(selectField, hideField, hideValue) {
    $(selectField).change(function (event) {
        if ($(this).val() == hideValue) {
            $(hideField).hide();
        } else {
            $(hideField).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And then in each page you want to use it, wire it up like this:

```
$(function () {
    hideIf("#dropdown", "#fieldToHide", "no");
});
```

This way you could make multiple calls to hideIf on different select fields without rewriting the script above..

Comment: Ok, this is making it a bit clearer to me.Is it possible to inject this JavaScript into the page through a data annotation? So the the js or query is build up through a data annotations method and then injected into the page. Thus it's still being run client side but allows ease of adding it models. Rather than having the essentially the same script duplicated on each page

Comment: It's probably doable but I personally wouldn't do it that way. I would rewrite this as a generic function and just wire it up on each page.